# How to run a CABasicAnimation in a thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, cabasicanimation

```
for(NSInteger i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ....
    singleThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(changeLayerBackground) object:nil];
    [singleThread start];
}
```

the function changeLayerBackground like this:

```
- (void) changeLayerBackground
{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
    animation.delegate = self;
    ......
    [layer addAnimation:selectionAnimation forKey:@"animation"];
}
```

I found the the function `animationDidStop:finished:` only be invoked after the whole loop is finished.

Is there anybody have any idea about this?
Now, I thought this because the animation's delegate is self, the view controller. And the animation is invoked by a thread, so the delegate doesn't work. But I don't know how to change it. I tried to use the thread as a replacement, it still doesn't not work.

Any body can help me with it?

My goal is the when the animation is invoking, the loop should pause until the animation is finished, then the loop should be continue. until the loop finishes.

Comment: Shouldn't you be running your animations on the main thread?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to run your animation in a thread ? Because it already runs in its own thread. As the doc says CoreAnimation provides

> An abstract animation interface that allows animations to run on a
>   separate thread, independent of your application's run loop.

Maybe you simply want to chain animations ? If so look at this thread: [chaining animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854160/how-can-i-chain-animations-in-iphone-os)